# How can make this RxSwift based Coordinator more testable

Tags: xctest, rx-swift, xctestcase, coordinator-pattern

I am trying to add tests to an existing code base.

The app uses RxSwift w/ a coordinator pattern.

The `AppCoordinator` looks like -

```swift
import UIKit
import RxSwift

enum AuthenticationState {
    case unknown, signedIn, signedOut
}

final class AppCoordinator: BaseCoordinator<Void> {
    private let window: UIWindow

    init(window: UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
    }

    override func start() -> Observable<Void> {
        coordinateToRoot(basedOn: .unknown)
        return .never()
    }

    /// Recursive method that will restart a child coordinator after completion.
    /// Based on:
    /// https://github.com/uptechteam/Coordinator-MVVM-Rx-Example/issues/3
    private func coordinateToRoot(basedOn state: AuthenticationState) {

        switch state {

        case .unknown:
            return showStartScene()
                .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] authState in
                    self?.window.rootViewController = nil
                    self?.coordinateToRoot(basedOn: authState)
                })
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        case .signedOut:
            return showAuthenticationFlow()
                .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] authState in
                    self?.window.rootViewController = nil
                    self?.coordinateToRoot(basedOn: authState)
                })
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        case .signedIn:
            return startHomeFlow()
                .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] authState in
                    self?.window.rootViewController = nil
                    self?.coordinateToRoot(basedOn: authState)
                })
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }

    }

    private func showStartScene() -> Observable<AuthenticationState> {
        let coordinator = StartCoordinator(window: window)
        return coordinate(to: coordinator).map { _ in return dependencies.authSvc.authState }
    }

    private func showAuthenticationFlow() -> Observable<AuthenticationState> {
        let coordinator = AuthCoordinator(window: window)
        return coordinate(to: coordinator).map { _ in return dependencies.authSvc.authState }
    }

    private func startHomeFlow() -> Observable<AuthenticationState> {
        let coordinator = HomeCoordinator(window: window)
        return coordinate(to: coordinator).map { _ in return dependencies.authSvc.authState }
    }
}
```

The flow is as follows -
`start` invokes the `showStartScene` method. This will check if a token exists and if the user should see the onboarding screen. Once everthing is complete it emits an event that causes `coordinateToRoot` to be called, using the latest auth state to direct the user to the correct `Coordinator`

I have been able to add an initial test to assert that `window.rootViewController` is set on start, however I would like assert on the behaviour around `coordinateToRoot`

```swift
class AppCoordinatorTests: XCTestCase {
    var sut: AppCoordinator!
    var window: UIWindow!
    var disposeBag: DisposeBag!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        window = UIWindow(frame: .zero)
        sut = AppCoordinator(window: window)
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
        window = nil
        sut = nil
        disposeBag = nil
    }

    func test_on_start_root_view_is_not_nil() {
        sut.start()
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        XCTAssertNotNil(window.rootViewController)
    }
}
```

Each coordinator emits `Void` and then uses a map on the current auth service to call a recursive method and invoke the next, valid coordinator.

I was thinking perhaps I emit an event on the current coordinator, having preset the result of `dependencies.authSvc.authState` I could then assert on the type of `UIViewController` set as `window.rootViewController`

eg -

`XCTAssertTrue((window.rootViewController as Any) is SomeTypeOfViewController)`

What I would like to know is what would make this a more testable class without simply making everything `public`.

I have considered using dependency injection to setup the child coordinators and then using a stub to mock events, I am unsure if this is the best option in the context of something like `RxSwift`